# matching pairs within one column using another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

The column `samples` have multiple unique values, and few of these `samples` are paired to another sample (in the same column `samples`). This matched-pair is given by the `match` column. Few samples do not have matches as indicated by the *none* value in the `match` column.

```
library(tibble)
df <- tribble(~ `samples`, ~ `match`,
              "A0H", "B2D",
              "A2D", "none",
              "B4H", "A4D",
              "A1H", "B3H",
              "A4D", "B4H",
              "B3H", "A1H",
              "B5D", "none", 
               "B2D", "A0H"
)
```

I would now like another column indicating the correct *pairs*. Like so:

```
df <- tribble(~ `samples`, ~ `match`, ~`pairs`
              "A0H", "B2D", "1",
              "A2D", "none",NA,
              "B4H", "A4D","2",
              "A1H", "B3H","3",
              "A4D", "B4H","2",
              "B3H", "A1H","3",
              "B5D", "none", NA,
               "B2D", "A0H", "1",
)
```

How do I get here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this:

```r
library(igraph)
matches <- df[df$match != "none",]
groups <- clusters(graph.data.frame(matches))$membership
df$pairs <- groups[df$samples]
df

#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   samples match pairs
#>   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A0H     B2D       1
#> 2 A2D     none     NA
#> 3 B4H     A4D       2
#> 4 A1H     B3H       3
#> 5 A4D     B4H       2
#> 6 B3H     A1H       3
#> 7 B5D     none     NA
#> 8 B2D     A0H       1
```

The idea is to think your `df` is just a list of edges of a graph.
Based on that you can just use the functions from the `igraph` package to find the groups.

In this way, you can have a solid solution even in case groups are made of more than 2 samples. (Personally, I always suspect that there may be some hidden dirt in the data)